# matlab double integral over infinite support

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am trying to evaluate a double integral over an infinite support. Something like

quad2d(F, 0, inf, 0, inf)

but quad2d requires finite boundaries. Do you know if there exists an alternative functions that deals with infinite? With one variable quadgk does that.

Comment: Does your function decay sufficiently fast as you go out to infinity in both directions?

Comment: removed the continuous-integration tag as that is a different topic altogether, please review tag description

Answer (score 2):

You could use the symbolic equations solver, instead of a numeric one.

Since that is not possible in your case (as you stated in comment),
you could you approximate infinity with a series of integrals from 0 to M, where for each item in series M is larger than for the previous item. Continue increasing M until the change in result is smaller than your goal error epsilon.

Comment: in my case you cannot find a primitive of the integral function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a suitable change of variables to transform the domain of integration to a finite one (eg. a rectangle or a circle). The integrand would be in terms of the new (changed) variables and multiplied by the Jacobian of the transformation.